# Multiple align in equation with single equation number

Tags: equations, align

I'm trying to get the following equation aligned two times per line and also I want to assign a **single** number to the equation. This is the code I have:

```
 \begin{alignat*}{2}
  [M/H] &\cong\; 0.917 [Fe/H] &(1)\\
   &\cong\; 0.977 [Fe/H] &(2)\\
   &\cong\; [Fe/H] + log(0.638f_{\alpha}+0.362) \;\;\;&(3)
 \end{alignat*}
```

This produces the properly aligned equations but no numbering. If I remove the asterisks I get one number for each line, which I don't want.

I've tried wrapping the above statement inside a `\begin{equation}  \end{equation}` command, but it won't work. Ideas?

Comment: Use `alignedat*` with the exact same syntax wrapped inside an `equation` environment. However the `\;` after `\cong` are wrong and "log" should be input as `\log`.

Comment: The `alignedat*` command gives an `undefined` error. Are you sure that the right command? The `\;` are correct, I want those spaces in the equation.

Comment: Sorry! It's `alignedat` without the `*`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `alignedat` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  \textup{[M/H]} &\cong 0.917 \textup{[Fe/H]} &&(1)\\
   &\cong 0.977 \textup{[Fe/H]} &&(2)\\
   &\cong \textup{[Fe/H]} + \log(0.638f_{\alpha}+0.362) \quad&&(3)
 \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The `\;` commands you're using are wrong, as they introduce an asymmetric space. Also the chemical symbols should be upright.

[image]